# MySql move databases, new installation OSX Mavericks

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, osx-mavericks

Recently I made a clean install of OS X Mavericks, and right now i have setup ok mysql,phpmyadmin and apacheserver is running without problems.

PhpMyadmin as i was sure it will be, has no databases.
The databases are located in another disk installation from MountainLion that i was running before.

I understand that i can login PhpMyAdmin and export those databases in .sql one by one but there are a LOT,so i was wondering if there is a faster method to access the files and move to the Mavericks disk. 
I remember in another installation i was digging around and i found those databases in the disk but my problem was that they were directories and not just .sql files to copy/paste, and i think that i had permissions problems

By that time they were not many so i prefered to use standard method, export from phpMyAdmin and then import again in the other OSX installation.
I have root access for sql.

Basically everything is the same/carbon as the old installation of MountainLion (username,password etc) so i was wondering if i can copy/paste somehow method.
If permissions needs to be set correctly please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out MySQL Workbench for exporting and importing databases:

[Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

[Features](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html)

You can connect to one database and fetch data directly from another.

Comment: But what if the databases are stored in a disk and not on a Server?I tried to copy from /usr/local/mysql/data the databases to mavericks mysql/data/ folder. I can see the databases with phpmyadmin but they have no tables. I double checked and after the paste all the tables are still there. Something more to change?

Answer (score 1):

Allthough DannyThunder answer can help a lot other users (and i will choose it as correct) i will go with what most of the devs suggest, to use mysqldump.  
Problem was that i thought i will not have access to old sql that is why i had to copy/paste somehow the folders, i have backup allready and i am in mavericks and currently restoring. 
 
Backup (from another OS,server etc): mysqldump -u username -p -–all-databases > file.sql 
Restore (to the new OS,server) : mysql -u username -p < file.sql

Answer (score 0):

The others have given several good alternatives (I tend to use mysqldump as well), but I'll just point out that phpMyAdmin has no problem exporting multiple databases. Not sure why you think you have to do them one-by-one, but from the main page click Export; by default all databases are selected, you can use the "Custom - display all possible options" radio button to select certain databases only.